# How to calculate the lattice constant of NaCl using chemical information?

Tags: lattice-model, x-ray-crystallography

More specifically, how would I show that:

$a_0=\sqrt[3]{\frac{4M}{N_A\rho}}$

where $a_0$ is the lattice constant, M is the molecular mass of NaCl, $\rho$ is the density of NaCl, and $N_A$ is Avogadro's number?

Comment: How would you calculate the density from the lattice constant?